# KineticJS: Reading continous images and display using Kinetic.image

Tags: kineticjs

I'm using KineticJS to display images of a device similar to a webcam. To read the images I'm able to use a URL which return the JPG image. For testing purposes I have just added a event when the mouse cursor moves over the canvas. but updating the image fails. Only displaying the first one.

I think its a cache problem, but I'm not able to locate the problem.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

This is my JavaScript:

```
var stage;
var layer;
var dynamicImg;

stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: "container",
    width: 640,
    height: 480,
    id: "myCanvas",
    name: "myCanvas"
});

layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
//gets the canvas context
var canvas = stage.getContainer();

function drawImage(imageObj) {
    dynamicImg = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 640,
        height: 480,
        draggable: false,
    });

    layer.add(dynamicImg);
    stage.add(layer);
    layer.draw();
};

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
    drawImage(this);
};

imageObj.src = 'http://<ip>/live.cgi';

stage.on('contentMousemove', function () {
    imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        layer.removeChildren();
        drawImage(imageObj);
        layer.draw();
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://<ip>/live.cgi';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an alternate method that works faster and more efficiently:**

1. Create an html canvas element in memory and draw your incoming images on that canvas.

   ```
   var canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
   var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
   ```
2. Create a Kinetic.Image using the canvas element as it's image source:

   ```
   dynamicImg = new Kinetic.Image({
       image: canvas,
       x: 0,
       y: 0,
       width: 640,
       height: 480,
       draggable: false,
   });
   ```
3. Then you can just draw your new incoming images on the html canvas and your Kinetic.Image will automatically be updated with the new image.

   ```
   ctx.drawImage(yourNewImageObject,0,0);
   layer.drawScene();
   ```

This method is much faster and more efficient than recreating a new Kinetic.Image with each new image.

BTW...

I see your image source is 'http:///live.cgi'.  If that means you're receiving a series of individual images, then you may have trouble.  Individual images will take time to convert into individual Image Objects.  If you are quickly receiving a large quantity of images then the delay in loading each Image Object will probably crash your app.

Instead, you might encode your incoming images into a video stream and pull the stream into an html video element.  The html canvas can take a video element as a content source.  Then you won't have the problems caused when loading individual Image Objects.  Here's a link showing how to display a video element inside a canvas element:  http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It doesnt work. the ctx.drawScene() call creates an error: The Object doesnt support the property or the method 'drawScene()' is not supported. I tried to use the canvas in my HTML. Also no success. BTW: the live.cgi just returns one image, not a series. I will call it periodically to see a live image. Maybe the name(.cgi) is unhappy.